How to specify gravity model of trade with intranational (domestic) trade flows?
Having read the literature on gravity models, I would like to estimate one myself. Focusing on cross-section only for now, they take the general form:
lnTRADEij = aXi + bXj + cZij + eij
where  lnTRADEij = log exports from country j to  country i, Xi = importer-specific vector of variables (e.g. lnGDP), Xj = exporter-specific vector of variables (e.g. lnGDP), Zij = bilateral pair-specific vector of variables (e.g.lndistance), eij is error term.
Usually this is estimated only for i=/=j, but it is recommended to include intranational trade flows in addition to international trade flows and this is something I want to do, as I would like to estimate home bias. Usually importer and exporter-specific fixed effects are also included, which absorb Xi and Xj.
I ran the model in Stata including intranational trade flows with and without these fixed effects using both OLS and PPML. The coefficients were generally as expected. But I wasn't sure this was valid. Specifically, when i=j observations are included:

Unilateral variables appear twice - Xi = Xj. Or the fixed effect appears twice if they are included. Is this not an issue?

Bilateral variables become ambiguous in interpretation. For example, FTAij is a dummy for whether i and j share free trade agreement and would be included in  Zij. When i = j, it is unclear what FTAij should equal or whether it should even enter the equation.


Is a solution to replace all exporter-specific variables and bilateral variables with their interaction with a FOREIGNij dummy, that =1 when i=/=j ? So that bilateral variables only enter when we have an international trade flow and unilateral variables don't appear twice?
i.e. lnTRADEij = aXi + b(Xj x FOREIGNij) + c(Zij x FOREIGNij) + eij
Would this allow me to then include a HOMEij dummy = 1 when i=j as a separate regressor to estimate the home bias effect correctly?
i.e. lnTRADEij = kHOMEij + aXi + b(Xj x FOREIGNij) + c(Zij x FOREIGNij) + eij
Thank you for any help!

hey, cool question. You said "it is recommended to include intranational trade flows". Any chance you could give us a citation to where you heard this? Chances are they might have some of the answers we're looking for here.

@JohnMadden Hi, thanks for the comment. Examples advocating for intranational trade flows are Yoto Yotov's work, e.g. Yotov (2016) or Yotov (2022).

For the benefit of anyone with a similar question, I also asked this on Statalist and received a helpful reply from Professor Silva: https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1749008-gravity-model-with-intranational-domestic-flows
